# TYPO3 list module CSV export: First entry duplicate

Tags: csv, content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Is there a bug with list module CSV export?

When I use the CSV export feature the CSV list always has the first entry twice. See picture #2 rows 2-3 (duplicate entry).

It doesn't matter which kind of list I export, first entry always a duplicate. Current install is TYPO3 6.2.6 but I experienced that problem through all my installations from 4.x-6.x

[image: CSV export]

[image: First entry always shows up twice]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in gridelements extension. Seems that it is already fixed but not yet released as of Nov 12th 2015. Since there is gridelements and extension-gridelements2 extension I am confused which/where and when it will be released.

In the meantime: Disable `basic.nestingInListModule` in the extension configuration